# How to configure custom domain for links in Branch.io

Tags: ios, branch.io

How do I set up the custom subdomain for my branch links?  Currently I have pointed the cname records to xxxx.app.link and xxxx.test-app.link (I have added 2 CNAME records)

I get the following error when I try to add the sudomain in the dashboard – “Domain not properly configured; please CNAME your domain to ‘custom.bnc.lt’. If you’ve already done this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate”

Do I have to point the subdoiman to “custom.bnc.lt” If yes, then how will the live and test environment urls be different? Do I have to setup 2 different CNAME records - one for the live version and one for the test version?

EDIT:

It has been several hours since I set up the CNAME records. A simple `dig <my custom subdomain>` gives the correct result.

Comment: branch is amazing !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: You should use `custom.bnc.lt` as the CNAME for your subdomain(s). The Live and Test environments can use the same URL or can be set separately — completely up to you, since our backend takes care of all the routing details. Our guide for this is [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/dashboard/integrate/#change-link-domain), which you might find useful for reference.

Comment: hi Alex, thanks for all the great support BTW.  Just to be clear say our app is "Beagle".  We totally own the domain "beagle.io" and indeed if you go to "beagle.io" you will see our web site.   Do you mean, we would use, let's say **join.beagle.io** - and then, actually all we have to do is set the CNAME for  **join.beagle.io** to **custom.bnc.lt** .. and it will work?!  (This is assuming a subdomain .. join.beagle.io .. rather than a full on domain, perhaps getbeagle.com .)

Comment: Is that about correct?   PS yes, I read the excellent page you direct to above - I just like to ask to get personal service!  :)  :)  thanks!  Am I on the right track ?

Comment: Hi @Fattie! You are always most welcome. Your proposal Is 100% correct: simply set the CNAME for that subdomain and you're all set!

Comment: My pleasure. Any time!

Comment: @AlexBauer How can we map domain to branch.io? Getting below error , Domain is incorrectly set up; please use the nameservers below as your NS record. A CNAME record is not required. If you've already done this, note that it can take up to several hours to propagate.

Comment: Hi @AlexBauer i want to ask, the custom.bnc.it is this refer to live URL ?, or there's another CNAME for test URL ?. I want to make like this live : download.domain.app and for development : download.dev.domain.app. Thank you.

Comment: Doc Link is broken